# Peak detection / Slice discrete data

Tags: php, algorithm

I have been given a task, that given discrete data, like this

[image]

I need to slice it into 5 pieces, determined by the template it creates.

I am not allowed to guess a template, because every input looks different.

My approach was to find peaks in the data (above or below zero), then use that pattern of peaks to slice the data. Here is what I got: (not for the above data)

[image]

The top graph is the peaks in the graph, and because I know I have exactly 5 pieces, and 15 points, I can say that every piece has 3 points, and then slice it, which is the second graph in that picture.

Out of 40 inputs, I managed to do this only for 5 of them, because my "peak detection" algorithm is very very basic.

What peak detection algorithm should I use, that can also find local minimums, and has PHP implementation / simple psudo code? I am a beginner in this field of data analyzing, so I need your tips.

Finally, am I even going in the right direction on how to slice this data? or is there a better known way to do it?

**EDIT:**

My bad for not explaining before: the goal of this slicing, is to create a uniform not-time dependent model for a slice, meaning that long and short pieces will be the same length, and that is for each peak. If this is done per slice, just stretching, the data looks noisy, like this: (this is still in development, so I didn't write it before)
[image]

And I don't know how to do it without the peaks, because every slice has different times for different parts (1 second, 1.1 seconds, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Find the 4 longest sub sets without intersection in your data where values remain within some tolerance of zero. In the case that you don't know how many beats you have to isolate peak detection becomes more relevant as the number of peaks above a given threshold define how many sections you dissect.

I don't think you're the first person to attack this sort of problem...
https://www.biopac.com/knowledge-base/extracting-heart-rate-from-a-noisy-ecg-signal/

**Edit::**
As far as a peak finding algorithm I think this paper provides some methods.
http://www.ifi.uzh.ch/dbtg/teaching/thesesarch/ReportRSchneider.pdf

The approach labeled `Significant Peak-Valley Algorithm` more or less boils down to finding local extrema (minimum and maximum) in regions beyond (below and above respectively) a given threshold defined by some arbitrary number of standard deviations from the mean.

Comment: Thanks! I was mistaken not to include the reason why I need this in the first place, I just edited the post. I will look into those methods, and come back with results

Comment: Considering the edit I think you would be best centering your slices at the mid point between each significant trough and the next significant peak. The tricky part will be finding the right threshold such that you are getting the right points as peaks and troughs.

Comment: It looks like each beat has three legs, defined by 2 extrema and 0. First a descent, from 0 to a trough, followed by an accent from the trough to the next peak proceeded by the final leg, another descent, this time from peak to zero. By focusing on the beginning and end points of these legs it should be relatively easy to get the slices once you have the trough peak pairs.